# 2 stage heat pump and condensing boiler run off one 3rd gen thermostat

Tags: thermostat, heating, boiler, heat-pump

I have a 2 stage 20 seer bosch heat pump utilizing aux heat strip for second stage. I also have a navien condensing combi unit for domestic and hot water baseboard heating. Currently both systems are set up for two zones utilizing nest 3rd gen thermostats for both zones. The boiler is set up for emergency heat setting. One issue is when I turn the emergency heat on (boiler) the air handler fan kicks on as well. Is there a way to not have the airhandler fan kick on while using the boiler?
Next questin is how would you wire these systems up? I have hired 3 different contractors and none of them can figure this out. Is it even possible? I can tell you what the thermostat currently reads as being wired. Y1- Heat/cool, G- fan, OB- Heat pump, RC- power, W1- alt. Heat, C- 24v common, *- alt. Stage imgur.com/a/COawdQN Link is Pics of both systems.

Comment: you haven said WHY you want that

Comment: Hi Brian, please edit the question to add more information. Comments can get deleted.

Comment: I'll do my best to provide more info. What are you looking for? I'm not very knowledgeable, just home owner. Hire contractors to install and they don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Brian -- can you post photos of the wiring at your thermostats, air handler, and boiler please, as well as wiring diagrams (or at least model numbers) for the various parts of your system?  Finally, is the boiler feeding baseboards/radiant only, or does it feed any coils in the ductwork/air handler for the system?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel-- Thank you for replying. I just took all the pics, but can not figure out how to post them on here. Do you know how I can do so?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel-- https://imgur.com/a/COawdQN. link for pictures requested. boiler is feeding baseboards only. No coils in duct work. only a aux electric heat strip in air handler.